# Scrapy + Unicode class is using a lot of memory in scrapy crawl

Tags: python, memory-leaks, scrapy, guppy

I tried finding memory leaking solution Guppy and following results came up.
As you can see Unicode class is using lot of resources here..

Also,this only happens when I run this on my cloud instance it does not happen when I run this on my local machine..

[image]

Here, is picture of prefs() if it is any help..
[image]

Here as you can see Selector class is using much resources which it should not be.
Moreover I can't seem to find any solution regarding this on internet.
I am afraid I might be asking wrong question here..

Any help would be appreciated..
Thanks in advance..

Comment: is this the same question as before ?

Comment: yes, but that time I didn't know about guppy.

Comment: @jenishSakhiya maybe it could be because of the `scrapy` version. Check if they are different on the cloud and locally.

Comment: @eLRuLL both are same versions (1.4.0).

Comment: Also, is there any other way we can specifically find out what exactly is leaking memory?